# Is there a way to search a row in Excel to find a number that is between two numbers, and then return that searched number?

Tags: excel, lookup

I am trying to find a number in a row of numbers that is between 0 and 100. But for my output, I either want a "--" if there is not a number between 0 and 100, or I want the actual numbers that fit with that range.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNDZq.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you looking for the `FILTER()` function perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Use the logic you have already stated, just work step by step.
I'm assuming you want commas between the numbers, but you can adapt as necessary.
In a row under your input data (I'll assume it starts as B2), put in B3:
`=if(and(B2>$B$1),(B2<$C$1),B2,"")` and copy across.
Then in the next row in C4: `=IF(D3="",C4,C4&D3&",")` and copy across.
You either need to amend the formula in the first column, or (my preference) insert a blank column.
You then need to strip the last comma (E.g. `=left(P4,len(P4)-1)`
And it would be best to name the ranges B1 and C1 rather than just using $formulae.